# How does tar deal with hardlinked files?

Tags: tar, hard-link, deduplication

I have a 2.5 TB of data that I want to put in a 2TB hard drive to mail somewhere. It's not hopeless, as a very large fraction of the data consists of duplicate files. I am considering using [`jdupes`](https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes) with the `-H` option, which will replace duplicate files with hardlinks to a single file.

Here's the problem: **If I tar a directory containing multiple hard links to other files in the directory tree, will `tar` "reduplicate" them in the archive file?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably a duplicate from [Dereferencing hard links](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43037/dereferencing-hard-links)

By default, a single copy of hardlinked data should be included in your archive.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Fedora / RHEL, there is a `hardlink` package that will clean those things up for you as well. Then, as others have noted, `tar` will only store a single one by default.